# Access insert into one row characters from other

Tags: ms-access

I want to automate moving values from one row to other by using function like RIGHT, the thing is i need to take from one col (row) 2 last letters and put them into the other column but in the same id/row. ScreenShots should clear some things up.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run an update query.

EDIT (Thanks to @Applecore):

```
UPDATE tableName SET KodNrProjektu=RIGHT(NumerProjektu,2)
```

Before:

[image: Before image]

After:

[image: After image]

Comment: Why are you performing a `JOIN` in this statement? Surely you can just use `UPDATE tableName SET KodNrProjektu=RIGHT(NumerProjektu,2)`?